# Build a Recyclerview with horizontal scroll and stops

Tags: android

I would like to have a recyclerview with a horizontal scroll and stops.
A recyclerview with horizontal scroll is easy. You have to set a layoutmanager like a linear layoutmanager and set it to horizontal. Well, but now the stops. I would like to have a stop when the user is scrolling like a viewpager with fragments, so that only one item is visible. I am grateful for every help.